# how does wmode transparent allow to place html elements over flash object

Tags: flash, z-index, transparent, wmode

There are many questions about placing html content over flash 
https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=html+content+over+flash+wmode+transparent
and most prominent solution seems to use wmode=transparent param in object and embed tags.

I have the similar problem but a native plugin; not flash. My question is how does wmode transparent work, so that i can utilize something similar in my plugin?

Comment: Don't use transparent, use opaque